# How to install rhomobile application in iphone device

Tags: iphone, rhomobile

I am working on rhomobile framework. I developed a sample application using rhomobile.How do I upload the application to Iphone device.
Please guide me in installing the rhomobile application in iphone device.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options when it comes to iPhone (reference: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build#build-for-iphoneipad)

1. You may build the application for iPhone to test in the simulator
2. You may submit the application to the AppStore, following the same workflow as any other application
3. You may use iTunes to install the application on your local device (see section "Install Application to device" on link above)
4. You may bypass the public AppStore in lieu of the enterprise route (reference: http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf)